# Trigger load of elements without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium

This is going to sound pretty generic but I don't know how else to ask this question.

I am using **Selenium Webdriver** (on python) to automate the download of some images. I can access a list of links to those images after a search. The full list of links is of known length, but gets loaded after successive scroll downs.

For example, after launching the search, I may know there are 210 results, but only 20 of them get loaded. Scrolling down multiple times will load the other ones. Workflow example:

1. Insert search details, click search button
2. Read total number of elements
3. Scroll down until the number of displayed elements is the same as the total
4. Download stuff
5. Close download page, go back to point 3.

The scroll down is really painful because the image download is on a different page, and closing the new page will **reload** the original search results without all the scroll-downs. Meaning I need to scroll again.

In order to speed up this process, I tried using **PhantomJS** and upping the vertical resolution of the page. However, this does NOT load all elements and the process fails, probably because the vertical resolution is enough to load all 20 elements and cannot trigger the scroll-function to load the others.

So I'm guessing there is some function that gets triggered when scrolling down. But I can't find it in the page source.
What I know is that it loads a `<div id="loader">` that I see every time new items are getting fetched (and every time the page hangs because of connection problems).

My **question n.1** is whether calling the function directly without scrolling, (i.e. `d.execute_script("some_magic_function")` would save some time compared to `d.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")`). Perhaps not, so I should just use the actual scrolling behavior as I'm doing now.

But if there could be an advantage, then my **question n.2** is how I can find the function that triggered the loading of new elements (and of the `<div id="loader">`). I've tried looking for `onscroll` or just `scroll` but got nowhere.